# Keras weights layout confusion

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Recently I realized that in keras, the shape of dense layer's weight matrix is `(input_shpe, output_shape)`.

Shouldn't it be `(output_shape, input_shape)` so when we dot weight and input together we get a length `output_shape` tensor?

Also, why is the kernal size of convolutional layers `(*kernel_size, num_channels, num_filter)`? Is there any explaination to put `num_filter` in the end instead of `(num_filter, *k_size, num_channels)`? Personally I feel like putting `num_filter` on the first axis is easier to distinguish weights from different kernels.

Thank you!

Comment: where did you read `(*kernel_size, num_channels, num_filter)` ?

Comment: @QHarr create `Conv1D(4, 3)` and build it with a tensor with 2 channels, the weight shape is `TensorShape([3, 2, 4])`

Comment: `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size,.....` - first is filters. _filters: Integer, the dimensionality of the output space (i.e. the number of output filters in the convolution)._

Comment: @QHarr I am not talking about the constructor... The constructor does take in num filter and kernel size like that but the internal weight layout is different.